# Improve exposition of this proof: Matrix multiplication is associative, due to commutativity of underlying field

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, field-theory, associativity

I'd like to request tips on improving proof writing by taking a standard proof in linear in algebra which is nonetheless difficult to write well, and asking for verification and improvements.

I also want to verify exactly which underlying axioms are needed.

> Prove that matrix multiplication is associative, using the computational definition of matrix multiplication.

**Proof:**

Given $A$ (a $m \times n$ matrix), $B$ ($n \times p$), the computational definition of matrix multiplication is $$[AB]_{ij} = \sum_{t \leq t}A_{it}B_{tj}.$$

With $C$ $(p \times q)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
[A(BC)]_{ij} &= \sum_{t \leq n}A_{it}[BC]_{tj} \\
&= \sum_{t \leq n}A_{it}[\sum_{u \leq p}B_{tu}C_{uj}] \\
&= \sum_{t \leq n}\sum_{u \leq p}A_{it}B_{tu}C_{uj} \tag{*} \\
&= \sum_{u \leq p}\sum_{t \leq n}A_{it}B_{tu}C_{uj} \tag{**} \\
&= \sum_{u \leq p}(AB)_{iu}C_{uj} \\
&= [(AB)C]_{ij}. \\
\end{align}$$

$(*)$ use the distributive property.  $(**)$ use both the associative and commutative properties of addition.  It is interesting to note that while matrix multiplication is *not* commutative, its associativity depends on the commutativity of the underlying field, as it is that which allows us to reverse the order of summation.

---

## Update

Based on the feedback, I've revised the final paragraph.  Changes are in **bold**.  Review requested.

$(*)$ use the distributive property.  $(**)$ use both the associative and commutative properties of addition.  It is interesting to note that while matrix multiplication is *not* commutative, its **multiplicative** associativity depends on the **additive** commutativity of the underlying field, as it is that which allows us to reverse the order of summation.

Comment: What matters is that nowhere in the proof you need commutativity of _multiplication_. In addition, you use associativity of multiplication implicitly when you write $A_{it}B_{tu}C_{uj}$ without any brackets.

Comment: True. You can have a field $M_2$ of $2\times2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, and define matrices over that field.  An $m\times n$ matrix over $M_2$ corresponds to an  $2m\times 2n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$. Even tough the underlying field $M_2$ is not commutative (we're writing matrices whose elements are themselves $2\times2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$), matrix multiplications is associative and has the same structure as the ordinary matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s great to ask which axioms are are being used where.

Your proof steps are correct and clear but we never need to use commutativity of the field multiplication. When we swap the order of summation, we are just grouping the summands in a different way. Within any summand, the three factors still multiply (associatively) in the same order.

For example, multiplication of matrices of (non-commutative) quaternions is still associative, even though quaternions do not even form a field, but rather a “division algebra”.

Comment: Thanks! Revised for better clarity.  Can you take a look?

Comment: Sure that’s fine thanks

Comment: "When we swap the order of summation, we are just grouping the summands in a different way." - Doesn't that require commutativity and associativity of addition?

Comment: Yes and also distributivity